# Can I update data in an R package from a function in the package?

Tags: r, package

I have a package which provides functionality to work with metadata which is following a certain structure. This structure (and the input format) is defined in a google sheet.

I have defined a function (lets call it `update_from_googlesheet()`)which loads the google sheet and saves it to the `inst` directory and updates data in the `data` directory of the package.

At the moment, I am using that function only when building the package.

Now I am thinking: would it be possible to call that package on an installed package, so that I can keep the package as it is and update only the files in the `inst` directory (that should work) but also in the `data` directory?

Comment: I understand the interest of this, and I don't see why it wouldn't be possible in principle but I'm not sure if it's good practice as it would make your code non reproducible. In case you need to update very often (say more than weekly), I think you could have a function and run `data <- get_data_from_doc()` for every analysis. In case it's not so frequent, you might just update the package, or have the data live in another package which you would update monthly or so.

Comment: Reproducibility is a really good point. Thanks. I will leave it as it is, but leave the question here.

Comment: You're welcome, but to answer your question technically then, what obstacle did you encounter ? Do you just miss the general path to where the packes are installed to be able to change them ?

Comment: It was a question if there are any obstacles. As the data in the `data` directory is loaded, I could imagine, that there is something going on during packaging and compiling of the package, which prevents the change I was thinking about. Also: I would have to access the `data` directory via `file.path(system.file(package=PACKAGE), "..", "data")` which looks fragile to me...

Comment: I suggest you try it, and update your question if you get stuck. I believe R only locks dlls,not data files. As for it being fragile, well yes, you're bending the rules here :).